# Sendbird - how to do 1 on 1 discussion

Tags: jquery, sendbird

I'm trying to develop messaging application using send bird. For Group chat, its working fine. I'm trying to create 1 on 1 discussion, but I'm not able to find functions for the same.
Pls anyone advice.

OR

Should I need to create individual channel for the same?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this? I am facing the same query.

Comment: Not yet. I think second option can be use as workaround

Comment: I have implemented channel chat and set up the APNS for push notification stuff. But the chat window is not updated when coming from background mode. Are you facing this kind of issue?

Comment: nope. I'm developing website.